# Do any languages have interlaced phrases?

Tags: phrase-structure

Are there any examples of languages that can have interlaced phrases?

For instance in:

> I turned the light off.

one phrase is *turned X off*, where *X* can be a noun phrase. However, I don't think it's possible to split the noun phrase across the verb phrase in this case; I'm pretty sure it must be contained entirely within the verb phrase. If the verb phrase is split into beginning and end (`VPb` & `VPe`), is it possible to have a construct like:

> `VPb` `NPb` `VPe` `NPe`

where `NPb` and `NPe` are a single noun phrase split into a beginning and end? The phrases don't have to be verb phrases or noun phrases, or in that order, I was just using them as examples.

```
Embedded:                  Interlaced:
+---------------------+    +---------------+
|     +---------+     |    |     +---------+-----+
| 1Pb | 2Pb 2Pe | 1Pe |    | 1Pb | 2Pb 1Pe | 2Pe |
|     +---------+     |    +-----+---------+     |
+---------------------+          +---------------+
```

Are there any examples of a second phrase beginning inside another phrase and ending after the first phrase has ended?

Comment: No time to write an answer, but this is common in so-called "free word order" languages; it's sometimes taken as an argument against analyzing such languages in terms of VPs and NPs at all. See e.g. the examples of "double hyperbaton" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton

Comment: See this question and its answers: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/4294/9781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known under the term [Cross-serial dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-serial_dependencies) and is considered a rare phenomenon among the languages of the world. A famous example of cross-serial dependencies comes from Swiss German and it can be found in the linked Wikipedia article.